# Apache Spark - PySpark error

Tags: apache-spark, installation, pyspark

I'm using Windows 10 to set up Apach Spark to begin working with it.

The Spark version pre-built downloaded is spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.14

java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I already downloaded winutils.exe in folder `C:\Hadoop\bin`.

I set the environment variables:

%HADOOP_HOME% = C:\Hadoop\
%SPARK_HOME% = C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\

After that I tried to use winutils to set the permission to folder `C:\tmp\hive`:

```
winutils.exe chmod 777 -R \tmp\hive
winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive\
drwxrwxrwx 1 BUILTIN\Administradores DESKTOP-V0O6RLF\Nenhum 0 Dec 10 2017 \tmp\hive
```

But I'm getting the following error when initializing PySpark:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>%SPARK_HOME%\bin\pyspark
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/12/10 00:39:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 45, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 183, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"
>>>
```

The only solutions I found says to set the right permission to \tmp\hive but it didn't work for me!

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Use `spark-shell` before you fix the environment as it won't deal with this extra Python-Spark layer. Also, don't start _anything_ while in the directory `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. It's pretty restricted area that may or may not cause problems.

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski, and is there something that I can do with `spark-shell` to fix the environment? Or you mean to use this while I can't fix it? Thanks for the system32 tip, but it happens anyway...

Comment: Start `spark-shell` and the issues should be there too, but I think stacktraces should be more familiar. After you've fixed `spark-shell` you should work with `pyspark` fine too.